# Why do Android library modules have a manifest file?

Tags: android

Any ideas?  Im having a hard time searching for something so specific and probably trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [the library can contribute elements to the app's manifest](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger), such as permissions required by the library.

Comment: Are there dangers? ie. Declarations that could contradict eachother

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun: Contradictions are handled by the manifest merger process, described in the Web page that l linked to in my answer.